# Converting a 12h format to 24h format in JS

Tags: javascript, date, format

I want to convert a string date with this format "3/25/2018 11:51:46 PM" 
into a 24h locale format like this "10/05/2018 at 08:51:46" (french format)

When I insert this kind of dates "3/25/2018 11:51:46 PM" I get this "10/05/2018 at 08:51:46"

This is my current code:

```js
String.prototype.toDate = function(format) {
  var normalized = this.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '-');
  var normalizedFormat = format.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '-');
  var formatItems = `enter code here`
  normalizedFormat.split('-');
  var dateItems = normalized.split('-');

  var monthIndex = formatItems.indexOf("mm");
  var dayIndex = formatItems.indexOf("dd");
  var yearIndex = formatItems.indexOf("yyyy");
  var hourIndex = formatItems.indexOf("hh");
  var minutesIndex = formatItems.indexOf("ii");
  var secondsIndex = formatItems.indexOf("ss");

  var today = new Date();

  var year = yearIndex > -1 ? dateItems[yearIndex] : today.getFullYear();
  var month = monthIndex > -1 ? dateItems[monthIndex] - 1 : today.getMonth() - 1;
  var day = dayIndex > -1 ? dateItems[dayIndex] : today.getDate();

  var hour = hourIndex > -1 ? dateItems[hourIndex] : today.getHours();
  var minute = minutesIndex > -1 ? dateItems[minutesIndex] : today.getMinutes();
  var second = secondsIndex > -1 ? dateItems[secondsIndex] : today.getSeconds();

  if ((this.split(" ")[2] == "PM") && hour < 12) {
    hour = hour + 12;
  } else if ((this.split(" ")[2] == "AM") && hour == 12) {
    hour = hour - 12;
  }

  console.log(year + " " + month + " " + day + " " + hour + " " + minute + " " + second);
  return new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
};

logd = "3/25/2018 11:51:46 PM".toDate("mm/dd/yyyy hh:ii:ss");
console.log(logd.toLocaleString());
```

Comment: just wondering, is there any reason for not using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com)? It makes life easier in these scenarios.

Comment: what kind of question is this ? normally 24h converted into 12 h? what you want to do?

Comment: There is no conversion when using date. It's always a question of displaying your data

Comment: @MemetOlsen because you can do this in 3 lines of code rather than including a whole library to do it?

Comment: @Pete well, that's true, but i hope for him not to deal with duration, timezone and user personnalized format, because it will be really insane to code from scratch everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why everyone wants to use a library, why not just use a mixture of [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) and [`toLocaleTimeString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString):

```js
var options = { hour12: false };
var date  = new Date("3/25/2018 11:51:46 PM");
console.log(`${date.toLocaleDateString("fr-FR")} ${date.toLocaleTimeString("fr-FR", options)}`);

// or just use toLocaleString:

console.log(date.toLocaleString("fr-FR", options));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Moment.JS, a powerfull tool for date and time based project :

https://momentjs.com/

You can fin below your use case and some few sample

```js
console.log(moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY [at] HH:mm:ss'))
console.log(moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
console.log(moment().format('dddd'));
console.log(moment().format("MMM Do YY"));
console.log(moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY'));
console.log(moment().format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```